# Send sails.js variables to Javascript files

Tags: javascript, sails.js

Is there a way you can send variables from sails.js config files and make them available to other scripts? In my `/config/globals.js` I have a global variable `sails.config.globals.apiUrl` that I want to put in a javascript file outside the sails files without manually writing something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    globalVariable = <%= sails.config.globals.apiUrl %>
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think it is good practise, but you can use [node.js fs.write](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_data_position_encoding_callback) to create script file form config/bootstrap.js at server start and manually add it to layout. Anyway, this is very bad. Better consider some other way.

Comment: I can give it a try, doesn't seem too elegant but it should work

Comment: you want to get some value which is kept in the backend made available to scripts loaded on the front end, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels better to me that the fs.write solution suggested...

Expose the variables you want through your API:

```
myGlobal: function(req, res) {
    res.json(sails.config.globals.myGlobal)
},
```

And just make a simple JS AJAX call to that endpoint at the beginning of the scripts that need that value, and do whatever you want to do with it:

```
function httpGet()
      {
          var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlHttp.open( "GET", '/user/myGlobal', false );
          xmlHttp.send( null );
          return xmlHttp.responseText;
      }
```

Don't forget to expose that endpoint appropriately in your sails policies.